# JSON invalid literal when parsing

Tags: json, nlohmann-json

I'm trying to parse a JSON file using the free header only JSON library on Github called [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

The error I get is:

> "syntax error while parsing value - invalid literal; last read:
> '"hasGlobalMagneticField": false<U+000D><U+000A>
> }<U+000D><U+000A>]ý'; expected end of input"

The JSON file I'm trying to read is the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mercury",
    "mass": 0.33,
    "diameter": 4879.0,
    "density": 5427.0,
    "gravity": 3.7,
    "escapeVelocity": 4.3,
    "rotationPeriod": 1407.6,
    "lengthOfDay": 4222.6,
    "distanceFromSun": 57.9,
    "perihelion": 46.0,
    "aphelion": 69.8,
    "orbitalPeriod": 88.0,
    "orbitalVelocity": 47.4,
    "orbitalInclination": 7.0,
    "orbitalEccentricity": 0.205,
    "obliquityToOrbit": 0.034,
    "meanTemperature": 167.0,
    "surfacePressure": 0.0,
    "numberOfMoons": 0,
    "hasRingSystem": false,
    "hasGlobalMagneticField": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Venus",
    "mass": 4.87,
    "diameter": 12104.0,
    "density": 5243.0,
    "gravity": 8.9,
    "escapeVelocity": 10.4,
    "rotationPeriod": -5832.5,
    "lengthOfDay": 2802.0,
    "distanceFromSun": 108.2,
    "perihelion": 107.5,
    "aphelion": 108.9,
    "orbitalPeriod": 224.7,
    "orbitalVelocity": 35.0,
    "orbitalInclination": 3.4,
    "orbitalEccentricity": 0.007,
    "obliquityToOrbit": 177.4,
    "meanTemperature": 464.0,
    "surfacePressure": 92.0,
    "numberOfMoons": 0,
    "hasRingSystem": false,
    "hasGlobalMagneticField": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Earth",
    "mass": 5.97,
    "diameter": 12756.0,
    "density": 5514.0,
    "gravity": 9.8,
    "escapeVelocity": 11.2,
    "rotationPeriod": 23.9,
    "lengthOfDay": 24.0,
    "distanceFromSun": 149.6,
    "perihelion": 147.1,
    "aphelion": 152.1,
    "orbitalPeriod": 365.2,
    "orbitalVelocity": 29.8,
    "orbitalInclination": 0.0,
    "orbitalEccentricity": 0.017,
    "obliquityToOrbit": 23.4,
    "meanTemperature": 15.0,
    "surfacePressure": 1.0,
    "numberOfMoons": 1,
    "hasRingSystem": false,
    "hasGlobalMagneticField": false
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Mars",
    "mass": 0.642,
    "diameter": 6792.0,
    "density": 3933.0,
    "gravity": 3.7,
    "escapeVelocity": 5.0,
    "rotationPeriod": 24.6,
    "lengthOfDay": 24.7,
    "distanceFromSun": 227.9,
    "perihelion": 206.6,
    "aphelion": 249.2,
    "orbitalPeriod": 687.0,
    "orbitalVelocity": 24.1,
    "orbitalInclination": 1.9,
    "orbitalEccentricity": 0.094,
    "obliquityToOrbit": 25.2,
    "meanTemperature": -65.0,
    "surfacePressure": 0.01,
    "numberOfMoons": 2,
    "hasRingSystem": false,
    "hasGlobalMagneticField": false
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Jupiter",
    "mass": 1898.0,
    "diameter": 142984.0,
    "density": 1326.0,
    "gravity": 23.1,
    "escapeVelocity": 59.5,
    "rotationPeriod": 9.9,
    "lengthOfDay": 9.9,
    "distanceFromSun": 778.6,
    "perihelion": 740.5,
    "aphelion": 816.6,
    "orbitalPeriod": 4331.0,
    "orbitalVelocity": 13.1,
    "orbitalInclination": 1.3,
    "orbitalEccentricity": 0.049,
    "obliquityToOrbit": 3.1,
    "meanTemperature": -110.0,
    "surfacePressure": null,
    "numberOfMoons": 79,
    "hasRingSystem": false,
    "hasGlobalMagneticField": false
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Saturn",
    "mass": 568.0,
    "diameter": 120536.0,
    "density": 687.0,
    "gravity": 9.0,
    "escapeVelocity": 35.5,
    "rotationPeriod": 10.7,
    "lengthOfDay": 10.7,
    "distanceFromSun": 1433.5,
    "perihelion": 1352.6,
    "aphelion": 1514.5,
    "orbitalPeriod": 10747.0,
    "orbitalVelocity": 9.7,
    "orbitalInclination": 2.5,
    "orbitalEccentricity": 0.057,
    "obliquityToOrbit": 26.7,
    "meanTemperature": -140.0,
    "surfacePressure": null,
    "numberOfMoons": 62,
    "hasRingSystem": false,
    "hasGlobalMagneticField": false
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Uranus",
    "mass": 86.8,
    "diameter": 51118.0,
    "density": 1271.0,
    "gravity": 8.7,
    "escapeVelocity": 21.3,
    "rotationPeriod": -17.2,
    "lengthOfDay": 17.2,
    "distanceFromSun": 2872.5,
    "perihelion": 2741.3,
    "aphelion": 3003.6,
    "orbitalPeriod": 30589.0,
    "orbitalVelocity": 6.8,
    "orbitalInclination": 0.8,
    "orbitalEccentricity": 0.046,
    "obliquityToOrbit": 97.8,
    "meanTemperature": -195.0,
    "surfacePressure": null,
    "numberOfMoons": 27,
    "hasRingSystem": false,
    "hasGlobalMagneticField": false
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Neptune",
    "mass": 102.0,
    "diameter": 49528.0,
    "density": 1638.0,
    "gravity": 11.0,
    "escapeVelocity": 23.5,
    "rotationPeriod": 16.1,
    "lengthOfDay": 16.1,
    "distanceFromSun": 4495.1,
    "perihelion": 4444.5,
    "aphelion": 4545.7,
    "orbitalPeriod": 59800.0,
    "orbitalVelocity": 5.4,
    "orbitalInclination": 1.8,
    "orbitalEccentricity": 0.011,
    "obliquityToOrbit": 28.3,
    "meanTemperature": -200.0,
    "surfacePressure": null,
    "numberOfMoons": 14,
    "hasRingSystem": false,
    "hasGlobalMagneticField": false
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Pluto",
    "mass": 0.0146,
    "diameter": 2370.0,
    "density": 2095.0,
    "gravity": 0.7,
    "escapeVelocity": 1.3,
    "rotationPeriod": -153.3,
    "lengthOfDay": 153.3,
    "distanceFromSun": 5906.4,
    "perihelion": 4436.8,
    "aphelion": 7375.9,
    "orbitalPeriod": 90560.0,
    "orbitalVelocity": 4.7,
    "orbitalInclination": 17.2,
    "orbitalEccentricity": 0.244,
    "obliquityToOrbit": 122.5,
    "meanTemperature": -225.0,
    "surfacePressure": 1.0E-5,
    "numberOfMoons": 5,
    "hasRingSystem": false,
    "hasGlobalMagneticField": false
  }
]
```

Is there something wrong with the JSON syntax?

Comment: The error message states there is a `ý` character at the very end of your input. This is not reflected in the JSON you posted.

Comment: @trincot Thank you that was it. The string is supposed to be null-terminated and it was read from a file so it didn't have a null-terminating character at the end.